# import skimage works, but not skimage.measure

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-image

I am getting

```
from skimage.measure import find_contours
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-2cf88a5f2300> in <module>()
----> 1 from skimage.measure import find_contours
 
ImportError: No module named 'skimage.measure'
```

and similarly if I simply import skimage and try to call skimage.measure.find_contours I get

```
AttributeError: module 'skimage' has no attribute 'measure'
```

import skimage doesnt throw errors, only there seems to be nothing attached:

```
import skimage
 
skimage.__version__
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-846cd4ef3ef8> in <module>()
----> 1 skimage.__version__

AttributeError: module 'skimage' has no attribute '__version__'
```

skimage is installed:

```
(User) C:\Users\angel_000>pip3 install scikit-image --user
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-image in  c:\users\angel_000\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\edm\envs\user\lib\site-packages (0.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: imageio>=2.0.1 in c:\users\angel_000\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\edm\envs\user\lib\site-packages (from scikit-image) (2.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: networkx>=2.0 in c:\users\angel_000\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\edm\envs\user\lib\site-packages (from scikit-image) (2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: PyWavelets>=0.4.0 in c:\users\angel_000\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\edm\envs\user\lib\site-packages (from scikit-image) (0.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=4.3.0 in c:\users\angel_000\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\edm\envs\user\lib\site-packages (from scikit-image) (5.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\angel_000\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\edm\envs\user\lib\site-packages (from imageio>=2.0.1->scikit-image) (1.16.1)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator>=4.3.0 in c:\users\angel_000\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\edm\envs\user\lib\site-packages (from networkx>=2.0->scikit-image) (4.4.0)
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I found someone with similar problems here https://gitmemory.com/issue/scikit-image/scikit-image/3731/505817873
but no solution.

I also tried

```
from skimage import measure

ImportError: cannot import name 'measure'
```

Comment: Can you do `import skimage; print(skimage)`? Do you have a local file called `skimage.py`? Note that Python import will preferentially load files in your working directory to installed files.

Comment: @Juan I get <module 'skimage' (namespace)> ; I don't think there's any local files that would conflict.

Comment: Hmm, definitely something weird going on, as it should be something like: `>>> import skimage; print(skimage)
<module 'skimage' from '/Users/jni/conda/envs/cf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skimage/__init__.py'>`

Comment: Did you maybe call your script you are writing `skimage.py`? If so, that will conflict with the lovely `skimage` module you mean to import from.

Comment: @MarkSetchell nope, no such file locally.

Comment: This is happening with me on Colab

Answer (score 6):

In version 0.18.x it changed again.
Do the following:

```
from skimage import metrics

metrics.structural_similarity(grayA, grayB, full=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
import skimage.measure as measure
```